# systematic way to solve permission issue

Tags: postgresql

In the dev version of the db, things work.  In the hosted version of the same schema, I'm getting a permission error.  When I look at the permissions for the resource in question, they seem to match.  Thus the question, what is a systematic way of working through this error?

#### The permission error

This happens in the hosted version.

```sql
select api.register('google', '333344555');
INFO:  api.register: api
INFO:  api.login: api
ERROR:  permission denied for table auth_ids_link_user
CONTEXT:  SQL function "login" statement 1
SQL statement "select auth.login(auth_agent::core.auth_agent, auth_id)"
PL/pgSQL function register(text,text,text) line 35 at SQL statement
```

The permissions seem to match.

#### Working dev version

(PostgreSQL v13.1)

```sql
select grantor, grantee, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
from information_schema.role_table_grants
where table_name in (select 'auth_ids_link_user');
 grantor  | grantee | table_schema |     table_name     | privilege_type
----------+---------+--------------+--------------------+----------------
 postgres | api     | core         | auth_ids_link_user | INSERT
(1 row)
```

#### Permission denied on hosted version

(PostgreSQL v13.7)

```sql
select grantor, grantee, table_schema, table_name, privilege_type
from information_schema.role_table_grants
where grantee = 'api' and table_name in (select 'auth_ids_link_user');
 grantor | grantee | table_schema |     table_name     | privilege_type
---------+---------+--------------+--------------------+----------------
 doadmin | api     | core         | auth_ids_link_user | INSERT
(1 row)
```

The execute privileges for the `auth.login` function/routing reported from the `information_schema.routine_privileges`

```sql
 grantor |  grantee  | specific_schema | routine_schema | routine_name | privilege_type
---------+-----------+-----------------+----------------+--------------+----------------
 auth    | api       | auth            | auth           | login        | EXECUTE
```

Per @Bergi, given that `auth.login` is running using definer privileges, here are the permissions granted to auth on the table:

```sql
 Schema |        Name        | Type  |    Access privileges    | Column privileges |                                             Policies
--------+--------------------+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 core   | auth_ids_link_user | table | doadmin=arwdDxt/doadmin+| user_id:         +| Api can do anything when current_user_id:                                                        +
        |                    |       | api=a/doadmin           |   auth=rx/doadmin |   (u): ((util.current_user_id() = user_id) AND (current_setting('role'::text) = 'webuser'::text))+
        |                    |       |                         |                   |   (c): ((util.current_user_id() = user_id) AND (current_setting('role'::text) = 'webuser'::text))+
        |                    |       |                         |                   |   to: api                                                                                        +
        |                    |       |                         |                   | Auth can view all auth_ids to authenticate anonymous users (r):                                  +
        |                    |       |                         |                   |   (u): true                                                                                      +
        |                    |       |                         |                   |   to: auth
(1 row)
```

To echo the requirements: auth only needs to determine if an entry exists.  The api will insert a new record by way of an insert grant.

How should I "read-into" the error message to efficiently pinpoint the problem?  Answered.

### In the end, the offending permission

```sql
-- before
grant references(user_id), select(user_id) on table core.auth_ids_link_user to auth;
-- after
grant references(user_id), select on table core.auth_ids_link_user to auth;
```

Interesting "gotcha" that somehow slips through the cracks of a self-hosted, dev version.  The permissions were in fact too stringent.  I needed to expand the select privileges to include the fields used in the `WHERE` clause, not just the join.

The only noticeable difference I could identify between the two contexts is that the dev `postgres` inherits membership into other roles by default.  I had accounted for that in the hosted schema, so may not be relevant.

Comment: Who owns the function auth.login, and is it "invoker's rights" or "definer's rights"?

Comment: While I have not figured out how to report (direct observation) of the information you requested, per the schema: auth.login is owned by auth and executed using definer privileges.  The api role has an execution grant.

Comment: Which user is calling the function?

Comment: It seems there are two functions at play here, `api.register` and `auth.login`. Can you please share both definitions?

Comment: "*`auth.login` is owned by `auth` and executed using definer privileges*" - given that's where the error comes from, what you will need to check is whether the **`auth` user** has the permissions on the `auth_ids_link_user` table - not the `api` user

Comment: Great observation @Bergi. I'm looking into it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best use the command line client `psql`.

- check how the function is defined and who owns it:

  ```
  \df+ auth.login
  ```

  If `Security` is `invoker`, the effective user is the one who called the function, otherwise it is the owner of the function (also visible in the output)
- examine the effective user and its role memberships:

  ```
  \du user_name
  ```
- examine the permissions on the table in question:

  ```
  \z auth_ids_link_user
  ```

That should be sufficient to find the cause of the problem.

There is of course always the option that the hosted database is not really running on PostgreSQL, but on a fork where the permission system has been hacked up. Then you are at the mercy of your provider for an explanation.